# Changing App Name with plist data files

Tags: ios, objective-c

I currently have an app that uses a plist (stored locally) to save data. (The app is like an address book app). The code I use involving the plist is below:

```
- (NSString *)infoDataFileName
{
NSError *err = nil;
NSURL *dir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSAllDomainsMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:&err];


NSString *path = [[dir path]  stringByAppendingString:@"/infoData.plist"];


return path;
}
```

However, I just changed the name of my app. I redownloaded the app onto my phone, and none of my original data is showing up. How can I make the data from the original plist show up in the new plist?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you also change the bundle id?  If so then your app will be installed into a new sandboxed folder and you will have no access to the old files.  You should keep the same bundle id and just change the app name.

Comment: I believe I already changed the Bundle ID, can I unchange it and fix my problems?

Comment: Yes, if your original app is still on your device

Comment: Awesome! Just put the Bundle ID back to what it was before, and it fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed my app's name, I also changed the Bundle ID, which effectively created an entirely new app, independent of the old version. I changed the Bundle ID back to what it used to be, and the problem was solved.

You can view/change your Bundle ID in Project Overview > General > Identity > Bundle Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating new app, then you didn't face this problem. You just need to copy the "infoData.plist" file to your project and call your method.

If you changing name of your project and search your previous project name and replace with new project name.

May this helps.